# Connecting Reddit to Ifttt - Why are login credentials required?

Tags: reddit, ifttt

I want to trigger an Ifttt receipe on keywords appearing in a subreddit. 
When building a receipe Ifttt starts connecting the Reddit service and requires to enter credentials of the Reddit account.

Since I don't have a Reddit account I want to read Reddit without an account. 
Is this possible? How? And if not: why?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a Reddit account to use IFTTT with Reddit since it will connect to that account and create an 'app' to use the API. However, a Reddit account is quick to make since you don't need to verify your email!